# how to re-package the retrofit project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, retrofit

i have clone the [retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) project from github, and i want to add some customize annoation class then generate a new jar file.

i open the project with [IntelliJ IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), and i have config JDK and maven.

after `mvn compile` build success.  but the project seems like did't set correctly.

just like this

[image]

[image]

java file seems could not recognised by the IDE

Comment: try running mvn idea:idea ?

Comment: @nikeshjoshi i have resolved this problem.  `mvn idea:idea` still not work.

i fixed it followed the IDE tips, when i reopen the project , IntelliJ will prompt a tips at the right bottom of the window.  The tips means that can not find the pom file of the project , config as a maven project ?  Just click the yes button, then everything is ok. 

Finally, thanks for your reply!